# QtQuick - Dynamically rotate an image around the center of its parent while moving the image vertically

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qt-quick

I want to dynamically rotate an image around the center of its parent while moving the image vertically along a constant line - imagine an artifical horizon in an aircraft.

Example: https://www.aeroexpo.online/de/prod/sandel-avionics/product-173333-9879.html

Here is some code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

...

Image {

        id: horizonCard
        visible: true
        source: "file:///..."
        width: 1300
        height: 2340
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        rotation: bankSlider.value
        transform: Translate { y: pitchSlider.value * 1170 / 90 }

    }
```

Is it possible to define a dynamically chaning rotation center?

Thank you so much in advance.

Kind regards
Quintus

I already tried to use:

```
transform: Rotation { origin.x: VALUE; origin.y: VALUE; angle: VALUE }
```

Did not work out for me.